# How to get all unique unions of specific size between pairs in a list of lists?

Tags: python, union

I have a list `L` where each element is a list of size `n`. I am trying to find all of the unique "unions" of size `n+1` between each pair of lists in `L`.  For example, let `unique_unions_n(L,n)` be the function that does what I want

```
L = [['a','c'],
    ['b','c'],
    ['b','e'],
    ['c','e']]
n = 2
unique_unions_k(L, n) -> [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['e', 'a', 'c'], ['e', 'c', 'b']]
```

Note, `['a','c'] union ['b','e']` is not included because its union (`['a','b','c','e']` has a size greater than `n+1` .

This is what I have come up with, it produces unions of size `n+1` between all combinations of pairs of lists in `L`, but this does not guarantee the unions are "unique".

```
import itertools
def union(list1, list2):
  return list(set(list1) | set(list2))

def unique_unions_n(L, n):
  result = []
  for item in itertools.combinations(L, 2):
    u = union(item[0], item[1])
    if len(u) == n+1:
      result.append(u)
  return result
```

When given the same list `L` in the example above, my attempt produces

```
result = [['a', 'b', 'c'],
 ['e', 'a', 'c'],
 ['e', 'c', 'b'],
 ['e', 'c', 'b'],
 ['c', 'e', 'b']]
```

Which is undesirable because I consider `['e','c','b']` and `['c','e','b']` to not be unique. I understand my function fails because I am looking at each combination. I am also trying to do this in the most efficient way possible for larger lists. What am I missing?

(I was not sure how to ask/title this question other than through example, so if anyone has a better way to title this let me know!)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a set to eliminate duplicates:

```
import itertools

def unique_unions_n(L, n):
  result = set()
  for item in itertools.combinations(L, 2):
    u = frozenset(item[0] + item[1])
    if len(u) == n+1:
      result.add(u)
  return result

L = [['a','c'],
    ['b','c'],
    ['b','e'],
    ['c','e']]
n = 2
print(unique_unions_n(L, n))
# {frozenset({'b', 'e', 'c'}), frozenset({'c', 'a', 'e'}), frozenset({'c', 'a', 'b'})}
```

If you need a different format for the output, you can easily convert to list of lists/tuples.

Answer (score 1):

Just add these lines at the end of your code:

```
res=[sorted(i) for i in result]
m=[]
for k in res:
    if k not in m:
        m.append(k)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def unique_lists(listSet):
    res = [sorted(i) for i in listSet]
    outList = []
    for i in res:
        if i not in outList:
            outList.append(i)
    return outList

def unique_unions_k(L, n):
    k = []
    for x in range(0,len(L)):
        for y in range(x, len(L)):
            unique_set = set(L[x]).union(set(L[y]))
            if len(unique_set) == n+1:
                k.append(list(unique_set))

    return unique_lists(k)

# inputs
n = 2
L = [['a','c'],
    ['b','c'],
    ['b','e'],
    ['c','e']]

print(unique_unions_k(L,n))
# [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'c', 'e'], ['b', 'c', 'e']]
```